# Set Progress Bar tint before API 21

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the Progress Bar tint without using `setProgressTintList` method, as this method requires API 21.

For example clicking a button should change between this two modes:

[image: before] 
[image: after]

My code:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
    };



    int[] colors = new int[] {
            getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)
    };

    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

    ProgressBar simpleProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.recording_progress);

    simpleProgressBar.setProgressTintList(myList);
```